# Plotly.js - Making a modeBarButton a switch (toggle) with default OFF

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plotly, plotly.js

in a plotly.js chart (with react), I can add an icon and make it a toggle rather easily.
What is not so easy seems to be able to decide whether the button starts 'on' or 'off'. In my case, it's always ON.

Tried all possible combinations of the variables below, but to no avail.

Can this be done somehow?

```
modeBarButtonsToAdd: [
  {
    name: 'Toggle Hover Syncronisation',
    icon: mouse,
    click: toggleHover,
    attr: 'hover___',
    val: 'hover',
    toggle: true,
  },
],
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost did it, do not set `attr` at all.

```js
const trace = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
  type: 'scatter'
}

Plotly.plot('chart', [trace], {}, {
  displaylogo: false,
  displayModeBar: true,
  modeBarButtonsToAdd: [{
    name: 'Toggle Hover Syncronisation',
    icon: Plotly.Icons.movie,
    click: () => console.log('click'),
    // attr: 'hover__',
    val: 'hover',
    toggle: true
  }]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
```

Note: I used a default icon but you can set any `svg` icon and it will work the same. Play with the `.active` class and your toggle.

Hope this help ^^

Comment: Thanks! Yes, using your example, I'm able to get it working as intended. This made me search a bit more and I found that the issue is probably connected to React. Without the 'attr' attribute, toggle becomes 'ON' only when hovering over the chart. With 'attr' set to any value, I get the desired toggle functionality but the initial state is always ON. I tried my luck on codepen, but the way react-plotly apps are written there (sprinkled with React.createElement etc) is something I'm unfamiliar with, so at this point I'm not able to give an example of my issue there.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you would like, it's a togglable button but inactive as a default value?

I didn't manage to make it work with the param `toggle`. The state always begins as active.

Here is a workaround I made (react code):

## In Plotly config

```js
modeBarButtonsToAdd: [
  {
    name: 'Toggle Hover Syncronisation',
    icon: mouse,
    click: () => setToggle(isToggled => !isToggled),
    attr: 'toggle-hover-syncronisation',
  },
],
```

The attr will be added to the button in the dom: `data-attr="toggle-hover-syncronisation"`

## In component

```
function Component() {
  const [isToggled, setToggle] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div id="plot" className={isToggled ? 'toggle-hover-syncronisation-active' : ''} />
  )
}
```

A class `toggle-hover-syncronisation-active` is available when the button is active

## CSS

```css
.toggle-hover-syncronisation-active a[data-attr=toggle-hover-syncronisation] { // target the a element with the corresponding data-attr
  path {
    fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) !important; // override the color with the famous !important (to be careful)
  }
}
```

This can be a workaround until [this answer in the forum](https://community.plotly.com/t/custom-mode-bar-buttons-active-status/27842) doesn't change.
I only tried with Plotly 1.57.1, I hope it will help :)